# BEX64 error with mylibrary.dll_unloaded

Tags: windows, dll, loadlibrary

I have an executable that dynamically opens a DLL (mylibrary.dll) with LoadLibrary. When the application completes, it crashes. Exploring the error reports, it turns out that it gives an eventtype BEX64. One of the parameters is mylibrary.dll_unloaded. The rest is a bunch of addresses.

Does anybody know what this means and what's the possible source of problem? I have access to the source of all code involved.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue some time ago. When i call `FreeLibrary()` on exit, program crashed. The reason was a running thread, which was started by my library. Check you library for any running threads just before you call `FreeLibrary()` and stop them. Maybe there is thread in your main application that uses DLL function when it start to unload.

Comment: For others who may find that question: one simple way to crash is to create a window (CreateWindow), say, in DllMain, and then forget to destroy it when the Dll is unloaded (this may be tricky if the unloading is done from another thread). Any window message broadcasted to all windows will immediately crash the process, as the window procedure is now mapped at an invalid address...